# Can you limit the size of data that can be deserialized in Ktor?

Tags: json-deserialization, ktor, denial-of-service

In Ktor, is there a way to limit size of data that can be attempted to be deserialized from JSON? Context is defending against denial-of-service attacks where a malicious client might try and send a huge payload to cause out-of-memory issues

I've used a similar capability in Play before (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length). You can set the maximum globally, and also specifically override on individual routes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality in Ktor to limit the size of a body for deserialization. Still, you can write an interceptor for the `ApplicationReceivePipeline` pipeline to replace the `ByteReadChannel` (body bytes are read from this object) with another channel. The latter's implementation will count a total number of bytes read and throw an exception if that count exceeds some limit. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.serialization.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.util.pipeline.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 2222) {
        val beforeSerialization = PipelinePhase("")
        receivePipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationReceivePipeline.Transform, beforeSerialization)

        receivePipeline.intercept(beforeSerialization) { receive ->
            if (subject.value is ByteReadChannel) {
                val readChannel = subject.value as ByteReadChannel
                val limit = 1024
                var totalBytes = 0
                val channel = GlobalScope.writer {
                    val byteArray = ByteArray(4088)
                    val bytesRead = readChannel.readAvailable(byteArray)
                    totalBytes += bytesRead

                    if (totalBytes > limit) {
                        throw IllegalStateException("Limit ($limit) for receiving exceeded. Read $totalBytes.")
                    }

                    channel.writeFully(byteArray, 0, bytesRead)
                }.channel

                proceedWith(ApplicationReceiveRequest(receive.typeInfo, channel, reusableValue = true))
            }
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        routing {
            post("/") {
                val r = call.receive<MyData>()
                println(r)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class MyData(val x: String)
```